# How to find the smallest element that might have duplicates in a Linked List in C

Tags: c, loops, linked-list, compare, min

I'm trying to find the node with the smallest value(data1) in a linked list which has two data fields(data1, data2).

But there might be a situation that two nodes share the same smallest value in data1. If a situation like this occurs, I need to compare their data2 to determine which one is smaller(same value in data1, but the smaller value in data2), and then return the node.

I have something like this so far:

```
struct Node { 
    int data1;
    int data2;
    struct Node* next; 
};

Node *find_min(Node *head);
```

**New to C programming. How should I go about doing this? I really appreciate your help!**

Comment: Did you try anything? SO answers are usually based on some existing attempt, so that the asker can understand what's wrong with it.

Comment: No-code guidance: 1) traverse the list through `next` field until it is null. 2) Keep track of the minimum value (initialize it to INT_MAX). Keep a poiter to the whole node containing it; 3) compare each `data1` with minNode->data1. 4) If the previous comparison result in equality, compare `data2` with `minNode->data2`

Comment: BTW: `Node` is not a type name. Maybe you are using a C++ compiler?

Comment: Without using a `typedef` in your `struct` definition, this statment: `Node *find_min(Node *head);`  should be `struct Node *find_min(struct Node *head);`

Comment: The close reason doesn't make sense. The question is perfectly clear; it is just too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice way of doing this could be to create a small routine to compare two nodes, and then use that to cleanly decide which node has the minimum value. Something like this:

```
struct Node {
  int data1;
  int data2;
  struct Node* next;
};

static _Bool node_less(struct Node const* lhs, struct Node const* rhs) {
  if (lhs->data1 < rhs->data1) return 1;

  if (lhs->data1 > rhs->data1) return 0;

  return lhs->data2 < rhs->data2;
}

struct Node* find_min(struct Node* head) {
  struct Node* min_node = head;

  while ((head = head->next))
    if (node_less(head, min_node)) min_node = head;

  return min_node;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Now, explain this to your teacher:

---

```
struct node *find_min(struct node *head)
{
struct node *best;

for(best=head; head = head ? head->next : NULL; ) { 
    if (head->data1 > best->data1) continue;
    if (head->data1 == best->data1
     && head->data2 > best->data2) continue;
    best = head;
    }
return best;
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `continue`s if you combine the conditions like this https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/EE55ro

Comment: I prefer continue, since it is easier to read than combined boolean expressions.

Answer (score 0):

iterative

```
Node* find_min(struct Node* node) {
    if (!node)
        return 0;
    struct Node *min_node = node;
    for (struct Node *scan = node; scan; scan = scan->next) {
        if (scan->data1 < min_node->data1 || scan->data1 == min_node->data1 && scan->data2 < min_node->data2) {
            min_node = scan;
        }
    }
    return min_node;
}
```

recursive

```
Node* find_min(struct Node* node) {
    if (!node)
        return 0;
    if (!node->next)
        return node;
    Node *min_sub_list = find_min(node->next);
    if (min_sub_list->data1 < node->data1 || min_sub_list->data1 == node->data1 && min_sub_list->data2 < node->data2) {
        return min_sub_list;
    }
    return node;
    
}
```